# Firefox - max-width images not working within fieldset

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm working on a large form and have noticed that if an image is within a fieldset it doesn't obey the `max-width: 100%` rule.

It works as expected in Chrome and Safari but in Firefox the image overflows the container and the image keeps its normal size.

I would prefer to not make changes to the html structure and keep the images inside the fieldsets.

Anyone have any ideas if there is a workaround or why this only happens in Firefox?

**simple example**
http://codepen.io/FernE97/pen/NPZKaR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For purely CSS solution, check this link http://codepen.io/saig/pen/RNXLwY 
Tested with 800x400 and 400x400 image sizes

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: -moz-fit-content;
    max-width: -webkit-fit-content;
    height: auto;
}
```

You can check this link for max-width implementation by MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fmax-width#Examples

Answer (score 0):

You can try this workaround, width property defined. use max-width to overrides width property

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Edit : Please check this url : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwrWQK
I've added script which dynamically changes max-width property based on image dimension, hope this helps to fix your issue in Firefox.

Comment: Setting the width to 100% does technically work but if the image is smaller than the container it will stretch it to fit the container which I want to avoid.

Comment: I've edited my answer and tried to give solution to your question

Comment: Hey thanks for the attempted solutions, the javascript way could work but it would need to be updated on window resize to calculate the image width when the screen size has changed. Was looking for a css solution but looks like there really isn't one.